# Cannot install web grease via nuget because of permission access

Tags: asp.net, tfs, error-handling, nuget-package

I want to configure bundling to my new project. I have configured my project with `TFS` online but I cannot add any packages via `nuget` and always get this error.

```
The item F:\Project\MOC\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll could not be                found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.
The item F:\Project\MOC\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\tools\install.ps1 could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.
The item F:\Project\MOC\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\tools\uninstall.ps1 could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a nuget bug with older version. More details ,please refer the thread from GitHub: [Install package fails when solution/project is bound to TFS source control](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1164)

> The bug is during uninstalling packages, nuget will delete package
>   files from TFS, but if user set ***disableSourceControllntegration*** to
>   true, package files are not added to TFS workplace during installing,
>   so TFS can't find those files during uninstalling,
>
> The fix is to check disableSourceControlIntegration before deleting
>   package files from TFS.
>
> **Source Link:** [TFS Error "[file]not be found in your
>   workspace...."](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2739)

Also suggest you to update your nuget version to latest and try again.